# jQuery Datepicker onChange event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to alert the Date Selected when a user changes the date; I have a modified jQuery Datepicker that display month and year:

```
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    }
  }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```

After researching other threads, so far I've tried:

```
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function(event) {
  alert(document.getElementById("datepicker").value);
});

$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function(event) {
  alert(event.format());
  alert(document.getElementById("datepicker").value);
});

$(".ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all").click(function(){
  alert(document.getElementById("datepicker").value);
});

$("#datepicker").datepicker().on('change.dp', function (e) {
  alert(document.getElementById("datepicker").value);
});

$("#datepicker").change(
  function(event){
    alert(document.getElementById("datepicker").value);
})
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: How do I alert the Date Selected when a user changes the date?

Comment: Well, `.on('changeDate'` won't work since the datepicker has no such method. Or are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, using Bootstrap ...

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out ... added to onClose function:

```
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
      alert(this.value);
    }
  }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```